# Probability function (p.f) of a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, transformation

If we have a Bernoulli random variable $W$ that is derived from a Variable $T$ (Poisson $\lambda$), by the following rules $W =$ (if $T=0$ then $W=1$ and if $T>0$ then $W=0$), I am having trouble finding the pf for $W$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** We have $\Pr(W=1)=\Pr(T=0)=e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, the issue is that I need  to have a second derivative in order to find Cramer Rao and Variance,  so, shall i put λ^x e^-λ ?

Comment: The hint, which is close to a full answer, deals with the question that you asked. I do not know what variance you are asking about. If it is the variance of $W$, the usual formula or computation will give $e^{-\lambda}(1-e^{-\lambda})$. If your question is more involved than that, it would be best to ask an explicit separate question.

Comment: You are welcome. For the variance, we use the fact that for a Bernoulli $X$, we have $X^2=X$, so $E(X^2)=p$ and the variance, which is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$, is $p-p^2$.

Comment: Many thanks for your advice. So, if i have understood correctly, we use the Bernoulli rules on the Poisson distribution and make e^-λ and then we use the Bernoulli formula with e^-λ instead of P?

Comment: For the mean and variance of $W$, yes. For other possible questions, I cannot say without seeing the question.

Comment: Hello and many thanks once again. My main query was to know if the correct way to find the variance of the mean W, Var(W bar) is (1/n)(var(W)) for Bernoulli? The rest I believe I could proceed to work on solving myself (I hope!) - it's the only point I've got stuck and can't proceed..